# How do I make a HttpPost request to RESTful webservice to pass an URL with parameters which includes an array of values?

Tags: android, json, web-services, http-post

I am trying to make a call to a RESTful webservice to get JSON object. Now I tried making the call through HttpGet and was successful. The URL I need to pass was pretty much like this: http://example.com/ /def.xxx?Name=save&Code=sample&OrderDetails=[{“Count”: “2”, “ID”: “1”, “Price”: “5”}]. I

`

```
StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder("http://example.com/def.xxx?");
URL.append("Name="+name+"&");
URL.append("Code="+code+"&");
URL.append("Details=%5b");
            int val = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    if (val > 0)
                    {URL.append(",");
                    }
                    else
                        val = 1;                
            URL.append(.....);
URLX = URL.toString();
httpGet = new HttpGet(URLX); 
response = client1.execute(httpGet);
```

`

Now, what should I do if I want to make HttpPost call instead of HttpGet call? I tried in this way,

```
String URL = "http://example.com/def.xxx";

    DefaultHttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
    ArrayList<NameValue> postParameters;

    postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", name));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Code", code));

try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


                response = client1.execute(httpPost);
```

}
Now I am not sure how should I add the values pairs in Details=[{“Count”: “2”, “ID”: “1”, “Price”: “5”}] in the Post call and how should I execute it to get the same JSON object as I am getting while making HttpGet call. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;

postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", name));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Code", sample));
```

To construct JSONArray or JSONObject You can [checkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718093/1398150).

```
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OrderDetails",jOrderdetails));

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

**EDIT:-**

for OrderDetailsObject you can construct it as follows..

```
JSONArray jOrderdetails = new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
JSONObject childObject = new JSONObject();
childObject.put("Count",countvalue);
childObject.put("ID",IDvalue);
childObject.put("Price",Pricevalue);
jOrderdetails.put(childObject).toString();
}
```

in the above shown way you can construct the JSONArray and then that object you need to pass as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With OrderDetails I need to pass in this way: OrderDetails=[{“Count”: “2”, “ID”: “1”, “Price”: “5”}, {“Count”: “3”, “ID”: “3”, “Price”: “3”}]. And all these are Strings. In this case how should I create the OrderDetailsObject? Also, do I need to include the ? after .ashx in URL?

Comment: I tried in this way considering the JSONARRAY example you provided:  inParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); for (int i = 0; i<len; i++){
      inParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Count", count+i));
      inParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID", id+i));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OrderItemDetails", inParameters);
But getting The constructor BasicNameValuePair(String, ArrayList<NameValuePair>) is undefined error message.

Comment: Also, do I need to put any HttpHeader?