# I want to generate NAMEVALUEPAIR for this type of json structure

Tags: android

{
    "name": "ABC",
    "title": "bcd",
    "looper": {
        "l1": "ghi",
        "l2": "jkl"
    }
}

How can we achieve name value Pair using such a format.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have done basic things using name value pair and this type of structure can be done by using JSONobject but i want to achieve it using BasicNameValuePair. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create JSON format data in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717838/how-to-create-json-format-data-in-android)

Comment: @y.feizi . Thanks bro for your time. I already have done using that method. I just wanted to make sure if i can do it using name value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like following method:

```
public JSONObject writeJSON() {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.put("name", "ABC");
        object.put("title", "bcd");
        JSONObject innerObject = new JSONObject();
        innerObject.put("l1", "ghi");
        innerObject.put("l2", "jkl");
        object.put("looper", innerObject);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;
}
```

Comment: hashmap or hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

For doing so you have to make Json Object to send data.It work similary to Name Pair value.